# Bart Mendelson. Introduction to Topology. Prove that $(X' , d')$ is a metric space given that $d'(f,g)= l.u.b \bigcup_{x\in[a,b]}\{|f(x) - g(x)|\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you check my answer?

This is problem 5 on page 34, chapter 2, section 2.

Let $X'$ be the set of all bounded functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$. For $f,g \in X'$ define
$$
d'(f,g)= l.u.b \bigcup_{x\in[a,b]}\{|f(x) - g(x)|\}
$$
where $l.u.b.$ means the least upper bound.

Prove that $(X',d')$ is a metric space.

**Solution:**

We can call a pair $(X, d)$ a metric space is the function $d: X \times X \rightarrow R$ fulfills the following requirements:

1. $d(x,y) \geq 0$ for $x,y \in X$
2. $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$ for $x, y \in X$
3. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for $x,y \in X$
4. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for $x,y,z \in X$

I will start with noting that the $d'$ function is the maximum of the absolute value of the difference between $f$ and $g$

$d'(f,g) = max |f(x) - g(x)|$ for $x \in [a, b]$.

The function fulfills the 1st requirement  because $|a| > 0$ for any real $a$. It also fulfills 2nd requirement, because $max(|f(x) - g(x)|) = 0$ when $f(x) = g(x)$ because $a - a = 0$. It fulfills the 3rd requirement because of $|a - b| = |b-a|$. The most interesting thing to prove is the 4th requirement. To prove it I will firstly say that $max\ a(x) + max\ b(x) \geq max(a(x)+b(x))$ and that inequality $d(f,h) \leq d(f,g) + d(g,h)$ can also be equivalently written down as $max\ a(x) + max\ b(x) \geq max(a(x) + b(x))$ where $a(x) = |f(x) - g(x)|$, $b(x)  = |g(x) - h(x)|$ and $a(x) + b(x) = |f(x) - h(x)|$ which proves the last requirement.

Comment: The max may not exist, the supremum always does. You shouldn't (and can't) use them interchangeably here

Comment: If I used supremum, would the proof be correct?